# error in linking phone authentication with email/password authentication

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I am trying to link email authentication with phone authentication but I am getting an error " java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot create PhoneAuthCredential without either verificationProof, sessionInfo, ortemprary proof" find my code to link the two auth providers below. please point me in the right direction

```
// [START sign_in_with_phone]



private void linkWithCredential() {
    final PhoneAuthCredential credential = PhoneAuthProvider.getCredential(mVerificationId,mVerificationField.getText().toString());
    firebaseauth.getCurrentUser().linkWithCredential(credential)
            .addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                    if (!task.isSuccessful()) {
                        Log.d(TAG, "linkWithCredential:success");
                        FirebaseUser user = task.getResult().getUser();
                        updateUI(user);
                    } else {
                        Log.w(TAG, "linkWithCredential:failure", task.getException());
                        Toast.makeText(Phone_Auth.this, "Authentication failed.",
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        updateUI(null);
                    }
                }
            });
}
// [END sign_in_with_phone]
```

Comment: Can you check `mVerificationId` and `mVerificationField.getText().toString()` are not empty?

Comment: i got it to work but thanks for your input

Comment: @DarkShadow Facing the same issue. How did you solve?

Comment: @sanidhya09 i posted the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i solved the problem but forgot to post an answer here's the solution code=

```
private void linkWithCredential(AuthCredential credential) {
           firebaseauth.getCurrentUser().linkWithCredential(credential)
            .addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                    if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                        Log.d(TAG, "linkWithCredential:success");
                        FirebaseUser user = task.getResult().getUser();
                        updateUI(user);
                    } else {
                        Log.w(TAG, "linkWithCredential:failure", task.getException());
                        Toast.makeText(Phone_Auth.this, "Authentication failed.",
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        updateUI(null);
                    }
                }
            });
}
```